# How do I use the Google Maps API GPS sensor?

Tags: gps, google-maps, sensors

All I've been able to find is how to specify the sensor parameter:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/#SpecifyingSensor

But nowhere does it say how to actually USE it.  Isn't the whole point to be able to get the user's current lat/long coordinates through the device GPS, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That sensor parameter is only there to indicate to Google that you are using a GPS sensor to determine the user's location.

Unless using the [W3C Geolocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API) in browsers that support it, it remains your responsibility to get the latitude and longitude from your GPS device to the user's browser.

Comment: Aah, I must have thought there was a magical conduit that allowed GMaps to get the GPS info from the iPhone.  Thanks for the enlightenment.

Comment: I don't get why google is so insistent on this parameter being passed via the webservice. What interest or use is it to them?

Comment: @skaffman: I've also been wondering the same thing. They might use it to collect information on how the free maps api is being used. That is, if they trust that everyone sets it appropriately.

Comment: I've been wondering that too. Why should they care? How can they trust it? It seems daft.

Comment: @skaffman Your question has been answered [What is the sensor parameter in Google Places API good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616764/what-is-the-sensor-parameter-in-google-places-api-good-for/8618552#8618552)