# What is the `sensor` parameter for in the Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

The [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) requests have a `sensor` parameter? How does this parameter affect the results?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Edit: The sensor parameter is no longer required, and will now be ignored if it's used.

The parameter doesn't impact the results. It's a parameter that Google is required to collect for Google's data providers who charge differently based on whether the request uses a sensor or not.

see [Google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required)

Comment: Really? Could you please provide some link, where this is written. I have not found this anywhere. (Also wondering why the price is different and what is cheaper:)

Comment: It's not in the documentation. I work on the Google Maps API team.

Comment: Ok. Btw, what is cheaper? Using a sensor or not?

Comment: Bizarre. And intriguing. And enlightening.  Thanks @ManoMarks.

Comment: @ManoMarks I was wondering if I should set the sensor=true always if the *device* has a GPS sensor it uses to get the user position or if I should only use it if that location is the actual found GPS location? I'm building an app where we show a map with users location but the user might drag the map and we do a georequest based on the new location. In this case should I start with setting sensor=true and then switch to use sensor=false?

Comment: @PeterTheill If you're using a sensor at all to detect someone's location, then use sensor=true, even if they drag away from the map. If you instantiate a map that does not use the sensor to detect the location, then set it to false

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Answer (score 21):

The Google Maps docs have been updated and as of June 2014 and the &sensor parameter is no longer required for JavaScript or Web Service API calls.  The parameter will now be ignored if passed along with any request.

docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 13):

Just to be more clear. If your script tag looks like this:

`<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>`

Then you should change it to the following to remove this warning:

`<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>`