# What is the effect of setting sensor true in Google Map APIs?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I know that I have to set sensor true If the position of the user is being obtained by ,let say a GPS module. But what does setting this parameter do in action ?
Thanks.

Comment: the sensor parameter is only used to inform Google that you're using a sensor to locate the user. It does nothing otherwise.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616764/what-is-the-sensor-parameter-in-google-places-api-good-for