# Google Maps places API to only return cities?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Google's map API to only return cities from their json request:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=green%20lanes&types=geocode&sensor=false&types=regions&key=*API KEY HERE*
```

The key being `&types=regions` but it still returns all results.

For example, I am searching for the street `Green Lanes` and rather than returning cities that might contain `Green Lanes` its returning the street in London as the top result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=green%20lanes&types=geocode&sensor=false&types=regions&key=*API KEY HERE*

should be

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=green%20lanes&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=*API KEY HERE*

ZERO RESULTS, because regions does not search for street name:

the (regions) type collection instructs the Place service to return any result matching the following types:
locality
sublocality
postal_code
country
administrative_area1
administrative_area2

Comment: Yep, but changing green lanes to london (or whatever city( will return cities that contain london.

Comment: Spend half a day to just get cities out of autocomplete. Million thanks to you

Comment: Hey @RohanKandwal , rob can you please provide me a fiddle that shows only city names?

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere sorry bro, I used it in Android using GSON parser.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but the accepted answer is not correct for the specific question.

The correct argument for the `types` parameter to return only cities is `(cities)`. So the complete URL would be:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=green%20lanes&types=(cities)&key= *API_KEY_HERE*

You can see more information [here](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table3). Also, I omitted the `sensor` parameter since [it's not needed anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616764/what-is-the-sensor-parameter-for-in-the-google-places-api).

Answer (score 0):

This is from the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types:

The (cities) type collection instructs the Places service to return results that match locality or administrative_area_level_3.