# The Google Time Zone API Usage Limits

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-timezone

I wish to use [Google Time Zone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/#Limits) in my android app. In their **Usage Limits**, they said as below.

> Use of the Google Time Zone API is subject to a limit of 2,500
>   per 24 hour period. Maps for Business customers receive 100,000
>   requests per 24 hour period.

Is this 24 hour period limit is **per user** of my android application or **whole users** of my android application ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limits are per ip address. Please note, some mobile networks are going to share ip addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Limit is based on the individual users. Each user is going to have their own email id logged in. So whichever request is called is based on their gmail Ids.

Comment: Are you dead sure ? is there any official document regarding this ? because when i call this [url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=-37.8136,144.9631&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=true) without login to my email account, i can get the result.

Comment: I am 100% sure but not `dead`.

Comment: ohh :D. Do you know about the `sensor` param in above url ? what is the actual purpose of that ?

Comment: [What is the `sensor` parameter in Google Places API good for?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8616764/3171838)